# Why does Google Chrome use the wrong device pixel ratio to choose the image size on a Moto G4?

Tags: images, mobile, google-chrome

Google Chrome takes account of DPR(device pixel ratio) while calculating Image width to download for a specific device.

But recently I found an anomaly. I simulated on (Moto G4 device having DPR 3) using Google Chrome developers tool.

If we calculate, Google Chrome should download 1100w image ((310*3=930px)>900px), but it is downloading 900w Image.
and I tested more and found that Google Chrome is taking 2.72 rather than 3 as DPR to calculate Image resolution.

Why is this happening? why Google Chrome is not taking 3 as DPR.

Here is the image.

`<img sizes="(max-width:380px) 310px,1100px" src="/images/90s1.jpg" srcset="/simages/90s1.jpg 800w, /mimages/90s1.jpg 900w, /images/90s1.jpg 1100w" />`